# Selenium Code is working but WATIR code fails to produce the result

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

In my application, I am writing the following code

```
b.element(id: 'B10_1_4').click
```

It's not working and it's throwing the unable to locate the element but when I write the following corresponding selenium code, it works fine

```
b.driver.find_element(id: 'B10_1_4').click
```

Can any one suggest me what might be the problem here? I have debugged through the coding, WATIR `element` of function calls `find_element` function internally but it fails but it succeeds when I directly makes selenium `find_element` call as I have given in the second line.

Comment: What error are you seeing in particular? Watir changed its approach to interacting with elements in 6.4, so upgrading to that might address your issue as well. If you are still having an issue you can add this code after requiring selenium-webdriver to see exactly what the driver is responding to: `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :info`

Comment: @titusfortner I have upgraded to WATIR version 6.3.0 to 6.5.0, I am still getting the problem. It says `Uncaught exception: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::HTMLElement: located: false; {:id=>"B10_1_4"}> to be located` If you want the log result where would I give you? Do I have to come to watir general?

Comment: you can post a link to a gist with the log output. Please include logs for both working and non-working code.

Comment: @titusfortner I don't know how to create that. Can I create the thread in watir-general where I can post log, what do you say?

Comment: copy paste results to: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: @titusfortner Okay, created the link is 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/38283d2f1dd85d72955e10a3cd5f5117

Comment: @titusfortner While I write `driver.find_element(id: 'B10_1_4').click`, it successfully executes and created the following log
`2017-07-26 15:15:11 INFO Selenium -> POST session/7d3639d9-e684-4123-804a-3fd8ca178ffc/element
2017-07-26 15:15:11 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:7055/hub/session/7d3639d9-e684-4123-804a-3fd8ca178ffc/element | {"using":"id","value":"B10_1_4"}
2017-07-26 15:15:11 INFO Selenium <- {"name":"findElement","sessionId":"7d3639d9-e684-4123-804a-3fd8ca178ffc","status":0,`

Comment: Well, it looks like it is making the same wire call, so something must be different in the state of the browser before the call is made. Providing complete logs would be more useful. Does this happen the same way in chrome? Also, verify you're actually using Watir 6.5; the line sending null to frame shouldn't be there after 6.4.

Comment: @titusfortner Same problem persist in Chrome as well. I am using WATIR 6.5 yes! What other log do you want?

Comment: This discussion was continued on the [Watir-General mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/watir-general/NEHQIQgOX-o/mSqTwHSWAwAJ).

Comment: What was the outcome?   would be nice to have an 'answer' to this here.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden The answer is the element is available in the frame which I have not switched to that, so the error, but through the driver variable I have already switched to that frame so the error hasn't happened.